# How to use XSLT to update a single value in an XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a giant XML file in which I would like to update a single value. Is there a way to write an XSLT file which will produce an exact copy of the existing XML file with a simple change?

For instance, let's say I have the following XML and that I want to change the position number of employee Martin to 100. How can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
  <!-- ... -->

  <Employee name="Martin">
    <Position number="50" />
  </Employee>

    <!-- ... -->
</Employees>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <!--Identity template that will copy every
        attribute, element, comment, and processing instruction
        to the output-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--more specific template match on @number that will 
        change the value to 100-->
    <xsl:template match="Employee[@name='Martin']/Position/@number">
        <xsl:attribute name="number">100</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4):

Start with an identity template

```
<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

add one template for your change

```
<xsl:template match="Employee[@name='Martin']/Position">
 <Position number="100" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you David! When I try your solution, only the first xsl:template seem to be executed.

Comment: In addition, the output of this solution miss the root node.

Comment: If the second template isn't executed, it didn't match the input, in which case it wasn't of the form you showed, perhaps your input is in a namespace? There is no need to match the root node explicitly as a root node is always generated in the output tree.

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:template match="/Employees/Employee/Position">
  <xsl:attribute name="number">100</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If combined with an identity template that would remove all Position Elements and add a number="100" attribute to _every_ _Employee_ element that had previously had a Position element child.