# Quadruple some Values in multiple XML files

Tags: xml

I got approximately 200 xml files in which i need to quadruple the values of specific Attibutes. They are way too many to do it by hand, so i need a script for that. How do i do that?

I tried to do that with a BATch file, but i did not manage to do that, i was able to replace strings or such, but how do i get the exact values of Attributes in an xml document?

could anyone help me, please?

the XML files look like that:

```
<AnimatedActor>
  <Content>
    <Spritesheets>
      <Spritesheet Path="MenuShadow.png" Id="0" />
    </Spritesheets>
    <Layers>
      <Layer Name="Main" Id="0" SpritesheetId="0" />
    </Layers>
    <Nulls />
    <Events />
  </Content>
  <Animations DefaultAnimation="Idle">
    <Animation Name="Idle" FrameNum="1" Loop="False">
      <RootAnimation>
        <Frame XPosition="0" YPosition="0" Delay="1" Visible="True" XScale="100" YScale="100" RedTint="255" GreenTint="255" BlueTint="255" AlphaTint="255" RedOffset="0" GreenOffset="0" BlueOffset="0" Rotation="0" Interpolated="False" />
      </RootAnimation>
      <LayerAnimations>
        <LayerAnimation LayerId="0" Visible="True">
          <Frame XPosition="0" YPosition="0" XPivot="0" YPivot="0" Width="256" Height="149" XScale="100" YScale="100" Delay="1" Visible="True" XCrop="0" YCrop="0" RedTint="255" GreenTint="255" BlueTint="255" AlphaTint="255" RedOffset="0" GreenOffset="0" BlueOffset="0" Rotation="0" Interpolated="False" />
        </LayerAnimation>
      </LayerAnimations>
      <NullAnimations />
      <Triggers />
    </Animation>
  </Animations>
</AnimatedActor>
```

Greeting - Manu

Comment: while perhaps not quite a duplicate I feel this overlaps with this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745141/how-to-use-xslt-to-update-a-single-value-in-an-xml  .You would need to run your xslt processor with a stylesheet something like that in your batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an xslt file with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<!--Identity template that will copy every
    attribute, element, comment, and processing instruction
    to the output-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- replace this with whatever nodes you want to target-->
<xsl:template match="Frame/@YScale">
    <xsl:attribute name="YScale"><xsl:value-of select=". *4"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

you can use Xalan from the command line to target your files with this transform
(https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html)

e.g.
java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN yourxml.xml -XSL NewTransform.xsl -OUT modifiedfile.xml

you can use a batch file to loop over all xml files in a target directory and aply the transform that way.