# Error in updating value on if condition in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to modify some value from an XML according to a variable. More precisely I would like to add `01-01` after the year represented in `<ao_production_time_span_from>` Here my source XML

```
<root>
<entry>
    <ao_production_list>
            <ao_production_time_span>
                <ao_production_time_span_from>2011</ao_production_time_span_from>
                <ao_production_time_span_to>2012</ao_production_time_span_to>
            </ao_production_time_span>
        </ao_production_list>
<\entry>
<root>
```

By following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745141/how-to-use-xslt-to-update-a-single-value-in-an-xml) suggestion from another stackoverflow issue I have defined the following xsl file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ao_production_time_span_from">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(ao_production_time_span_from) = 4">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(ao_production_time_span_from,'-01-01')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ao_production_time_span_from"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, as result I'm having an empty  `<ao_production_time_span_from>` as follows

```
<ao_production_list>
            <ao_production_time_span>
                <ao_production_time_span_from/>
                <ao_production_time_span_to>2012</ao_production_time_span_to>
            </ao_production_time_span>
        </ao_production_list>
```

My desired output would be like this

```
<ao_production_list>
            <ao_production_time_span>
                <ao_production_time_span_from>2011-01-01</ao_production_time_span_from>
                <ao_production_time_span_to>2012</ao_production_time_span_to>
            </ao_production_time_span>
        </ao_production_list>
```

Where is the mistake?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the `xsl:template match="ao_production_time_span_from"`, the context node is that element so to select it as an argument for a function use `.` e.g. `concat(., '-01-01')` and `string-length(.)` and not `ao_production_time_span_from` as that looks for a child element of the context node and not the context node itself.

As another improvement, you could move the `string-length` check into a predicate of the template match e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="ao_production_time_span_from[string-length(.) = 4]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '-01-01')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```